# mi código imprime sin parar

Tags: c++

el programa debe preguntar si es alumno o profesor, si es profesor debe colocar una contraseña, si es correcta debe responder el test pero solo Respuestas y ,si es alumno debe colocar nombre,apellido y rut, y de inmediato empieza el test de 10 preguntas con 4 alternativas

El error se encuentra en el case 1, si tu eliges la opción alumno( 1 ), te pide tu nombre, al momento de colocar tu nombre e incluso 1 letra, falla y empieza a imprimir sin parar todo lo que sigue, si eligo el case 2 (profesor =2) contraseña 1234,coloco solo las respuestas y al finalizar me da la suma de respuestas correctas

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #define clavetrue 1234
    #define respuesta profesor
    using namespace std;
    int opcion,nombre,apellido,rut,claveacceso,profesor,datoingresado,profe,s1,s2,z1,z2,p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8,p9,p10,n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,n6,n7,n8,n9,n10,resultado;

    int main (void)
    {
        do
        {
            printf("\nSi usted es alumno Ingrese opcion 1\nSi usted es profesor Ingrese opcion 2\nIngrese la opcion : ");
            scanf("%d",&opcion);
            switch(opcion){
            case 1:
            printf("Si usted es alumno\n");
            printf("\nIntroduzca su nombre: ");
            scanf("%d",&nombre);
            printf(" \nIngrese su apellido: ");
            scanf("%d",&apellido);
            printf("\nIngrese su rut: ");
            scanf("%d",&rut);
            printf("esta es tu evaluación cuenta con 10 preguntas de selección multiple \n");
            printf("pregunta1 \n");
            printf("En que mes nos encontramos \n");
            printf("1) Junio \n");
            printf("2) Julio \n");
            printf("3) Agosto \n");
            printf("4) Mayo \n");
            printf("Indica tu respuesta \n");
            scanf("%i",&p1);
            if(p1==2){
            n1=1;
            }
            else{
                n1=0;
            }
            printf("pregunta 2 \n");
            printf("En que año estamos\n");
            printf("1) año 2001 \n");
            printf("2) año 2018 \n");
            printf("3) año 2020 \n");
            printf("4) año 2019 \n");
            printf("Indica tu respuesta \n");
            scanf("%i",&p2);
           if(p2==4){
            n2=1;
            }
            else{
                n2= 0;
            }
            printf("pregunta 3 \n");
            printf("Que lenguaje estoy usando en esta evaluación \n");
            printf("1) Phyton \n");
            printf("2) C++ \n");
            printf("3) Java \n");
            printf("4) C# \n");
            printf("Indica tu respuesta \n");
            scanf("%i",&p3);
            if(p3==2){
            n3=1;
            }
            else{
                n3= 0;
            }
            printf("pregunta 4 \n");
            printf("A que nota corresponde esta evaluación \n");
            printf("1) a la 2da nota \n");
            printf("2) a la ultima nota \n");
            printf("3) a la 1ra nota \n");
            printf("4) a la 3ra nota \n");
            printf("Indica tu respuesta \n");
            scanf("%i",&p4);
            if(p4==2){
            n4=1;
            }
            else{
                n4= 0;
            }
            printf("pregunta 5 \n");
            printf("Cuanto dura la clase de Algoritmo y programación \n");
            printf("1) 1 hora \n");
            printf("2) 4 horas \n");
            printf("3) 3 horas \n");
            printf("4) 2 horas \n");
            printf("Indica tu respuesta \n");
            scanf("%i",&p5);
            if(p5==3){
            n5=1;
            }
            else{
                n5= 0;
            }
            printf("pregunta 6 \n");
            printf("Mejor seccion en el pinpon \n");
            printf("1) sección 520 \n");
            printf("2) sección 320 \n");
            printf("3) sección 270 \n");
            printf("4) sección 420 \n");
            printf("Indica tu respuesta \n");
            scanf("%i",&p6);
            if(p6==2){
            n6=1;
            }
            else{
                n6= 0;
            }
            printf("pregunta 7 \n");
            printf("De que asignatura es esta evaluación \n");
            printf("1) Introduccion a la ingenieria eléctrica \n");
            printf("2) Gestion del Aprendizaje \n");
            printf("3) Matematicas \n");
            printf("4) Algoritmo y programación \n");
            printf("Indica tu respuesta \n");
            scanf("%i",&p7);
            if(p7==4){
            n7=1;
            }
            else{
                n7= 0;
            }
            printf("pregunta 8 \n");
            printf("La mejor sección es: \n");
            printf("1) sección 420 \n");
            printf("2) sección 320\n");
            printf("3) sección 340 \n");
            printf("4) sección 270 \n");
            printf("Indica tu respuesta \n");
            scanf("%i",&p8);
            if(p8==2){
            n8=1;
            }
            else{
                n8= 0;
            }
            printf("pregunta 9 \n");
            printf("Jorge tobar es: \n");
            printf("1) Un tenista \n");
            printf("2) Un peleador de la ufc \n");
            printf("3) Un cantante \n");
            printf("4) Un profesor \n");
            printf("Indica tu respuesta \n");
            scanf("%i",&p9);
            if(p9==4){
            n9=1;
            }
            else{
                n9= 0;
            }
            printf("pregunta 10 \n");
            printf("Alexis sanchez es: \n");
            printf("1) Un jugador de futbol \n");
            printf("2) Un alcalde \n");
            printf("3) Un periodista \n");
            printf("4) Un cantante \n");
            printf("Indica tu respuesta \n");
            scanf("%i",&p10);
            if(p10==1){
            n10=1;
            }
            else{
                n10= 0;
            }
            resultado=n1+n2+n3+n4+n5+n6+n7+n8+n9+n10;
            printf("tu resultado del examen es de %i",resultado);

            case 2:
            printf("si usted es profesor\n");
            cout<<"ingrese la clave de acceso: ";
            cin>>claveacceso;
            if(claveacceso!=clavetrue);
        }
    }
            while(claveacceso!=clavetrue);
            cout<<"\n\n acesso concedido.\n";
            getch();

        printf("esta es una evaluación cuenta con 10 preguntas de selección multiple \n");
        printf("pregunta 1 \n");
        printf("En que mes nos encontramos \n");
        printf("Indica tu respuesta \n");
        scanf("%i",&p1);
        if(p1==2){
        n1=1;
        }
        else{
            n1=0;
        }
        printf("pregunta 2 \n");
        printf("En que año estamos\n");
        printf("Indica tu respuesta \n");
        scanf("%i",&p2);
        if(p2==4){
        n2=1;
        }
        else{
            n2= 0;
        }
        printf("pregunta 3 \n");
        printf("Que lenguaje estoy usando en esta evaluación \n");
        printf("Indica tu respuesta \n");
        scanf("%i",&p3);
        if(p3==2){
        n3=1;
        }
        else{
            n3= 0;
        }
        printf("pregunta 4 \n");
        printf("A que nota corresponde esta evaluación \n");
        printf("Indica tu respuesta \n");
        scanf("%i",&p4);
        if(p4==2){
        n4=1;
        }
        else{
            n4= 0;
        }
        printf("pregunta 5 \n");
        printf("Cuanto dura la clase de Algoritmo y programación \n");
        printf("Indica tu respuesta \n");
        scanf("%i",&p5);
        if(p5==3){
        n5=1;
        }
        else{
            n5= 0;
        }
        printf("pregunta 6 \n");
        printf("Mejor seccion en el pinpon \n");
        printf("Indica tu respuesta \n");
        scanf("%i",&p6);
        if(p6==2){
        n6=1;
        }
        else{
            n6= 0;
        }
        printf("pregunta 7 \n");
        printf("De que asignatura es esta evaluación \n");
        printf("Indica tu respuesta \n");
        scanf("%i",&p7);
        if(p7==4){
        n7=1;
        }
        else{
            n7= 0;
        }
        printf("pregunta 8 \n");
        printf("La mejor sección es: \n");
        printf("Indica tu respuesta \n");
        scanf("%i",&p8);
        if(p8==2){
        n8=1;
        }
        else{
            n8= 0;
        }
        printf("pregunta 9 \n");
        printf("Jorge tobar es: \n");
        printf("Indica tu respuesta \n");
        scanf("%i",&p9);
        if(p9==4){
        n9=1;
        }
        else{
            n9= 0;
        }
        printf("pregunta 10 \n");
        printf("Alexis sanchez es: \n");
        printf("Indica tu respuesta \n");
        scanf("%i",&p10);
        if(p10==1){
        n10=1;
        }
        else{
            n10= 0;
        }
        resultado=n1+n2+n3+n4+n5+n6+n7+n8+n9+n10;
        printf("has respondido %i correctas",resultado);

        }
```

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿por qué declaras variables como `nombre` o `apellido` como `int`?...

Comment: @FJSevilla en realidad no se si este bien o mal, soy un ignorante en C++ (es un trabajo para la universidad) , pero hago un esfuerzo en terminar esta tarea, la gran pregunta¡ ¿como lo puedo arreglar ? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando lo que quieras ingresar sea un texto como nombres, apellido etc. Declara esa variable de tipo string. Y para leerla usa `scanf("%s",&variable);` nota el cambio de `%d` por `%s`. Modifiqué tu código para que funcione con las variables nombre, apellido,rut. Si tienes otras variables en las que esperas guardar texto puedes guiarte por el ejemplo.

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #define clavetrue 1234
    #define respuesta profesor
    using namespace std;
    int opcion,claveacceso,profesor,datoingresado,profe,s1,s2,z1,z2,p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8,p9,p10,n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,n6,n7,n8,n9,n10,resultado;
    string nombre,apellido,rut;
    int main (void)
    {
        do
        {
            printf("\nSi usted es alumno Ingrese opcion 1\nSi usted es profesor Ingrese opcion 2\nIngrese la opcion : ");
            scanf("%d",&opcion);
            switch(opcion){
            case 1:
            printf("Si usted es alumno\n");
            printf("\nIntroduzca su nombre: ");
            scanf("%s",&nombre);
            printf(" \nIngrese su apellido: ");
            scanf("%s",&apellido);
            printf("\nIngrese su rut: ");
            scanf("%s",&rut);
            printf("esta es tu evaluación cuenta con 10 preguntas de selección multiple \n");
            printf("pregunta1 \n");
            printf("En que mes nos encontramos \n");
            printf("1) Junio \n");
            printf("2) Julio \n");
            printf("3) Agosto \n");
            printf("4) Mayo \n");
            printf("Indica tu respuesta \n");
            scanf("%i",&p1);
            if(p1==2){
            n1=1;
            }
            else{
                n1=0;
            }
            printf("pregunta 2 \n");
            printf("En que año estamos\n");
            printf("1) año 2001 \n");
            printf("2) año 2018 \n");
            printf("3) año 2020 \n");
            printf("4) año 2019 \n");
            printf("Indica tu respuesta \n");
            scanf("%i",&p2);
           if(p2==4){
            n2=1;
            }
            else{
                n2= 0;
            }
            printf("pregunta 3 \n");
            printf("Que lenguaje estoy usando en esta evaluación \n");
            printf("1) Phyton \n");
            printf("2) C++ \n");
            printf("3) Java \n");
            printf("4) C# \n");
            printf("Indica tu respuesta \n");
            scanf("%i",&p3);
            if(p3==2){
            n3=1;
            }
            else{
                n3= 0;
            }
            printf("pregunta 4 \n");
            printf("A que nota corresponde esta evaluación \n");
            printf("1) a la 2da nota \n");
            printf("2) a la ultima nota \n");
            printf("3) a la 1ra nota \n");
            printf("4) a la 3ra nota \n");
            printf("Indica tu respuesta \n");
            scanf("%i",&p4);
            if(p4==2){
            n4=1;
            }
            else{
                n4= 0;
            }
            printf("pregunta 5 \n");
            printf("Cuanto dura la clase de Algoritmo y programación \n");
            printf("1) 1 hora \n");
            printf("2) 4 horas \n");
            printf("3) 3 horas \n");
            printf("4) 2 horas \n");
            printf("Indica tu respuesta \n");
            scanf("%i",&p5);
            if(p5==3){
            n5=1;
            }
            else{
                n5= 0;
            }
            printf("pregunta 6 \n");
            printf("Mejor seccion en el pinpon \n");
            printf("1) sección 520 \n");
            printf("2) sección 320 \n");
            printf("3) sección 270 \n");
            printf("4) sección 420 \n");
            printf("Indica tu respuesta \n");
            scanf("%i",&p6);
            if(p6==2){
            n6=1;
            }
            else{
                n6= 0;
            }
            printf("pregunta 7 \n");
            printf("De que asignatura es esta evaluación \n");
            printf("1) Introduccion a la ingenieria eléctrica \n");
            printf("2) Gestion del Aprendizaje \n");
            printf("3) Matematicas \n");
            printf("4) Algoritmo y programación \n");
            printf("Indica tu respuesta \n");
            scanf("%i",&p7);
            if(p7==4){
            n7=1;
            }
            else{
                n7= 0;
            }
            printf("pregunta 8 \n");
            printf("La mejor sección es: \n");
            printf("1) sección 420 \n");
            printf("2) sección 320\n");
            printf("3) sección 340 \n");
            printf("4) sección 270 \n");
            printf("Indica tu respuesta \n");
            scanf("%i",&p8);
            if(p8==2){
            n8=1;
            }
            else{
                n8= 0;
            }
            printf("pregunta 9 \n");
            printf("Jorge tobar es: \n");
            printf("1) Un tenista \n");
            printf("2) Un peleador de la ufc \n");
            printf("3) Un cantante \n");
            printf("4) Un profesor \n");
            printf("Indica tu respuesta \n");
            scanf("%i",&p9);
            if(p9==4){
            n9=1;
            }
            else{
                n9= 0;
            }
            printf("pregunta 10 \n");
            printf("Alexis sanchez es: \n");
            printf("1) Un jugador de futbol \n");
            printf("2) Un alcalde \n");
            printf("3) Un periodista \n");
            printf("4) Un cantante \n");
            printf("Indica tu respuesta \n");
            scanf("%i",&p10);
            if(p10==1){
            n10=1;
            }
            else{
                n10= 0;
            }
            resultado=n1+n2+n3+n4+n5+n6+n7+n8+n9+n10;
            printf("tu resultado del examen es de %i",resultado);

            case 2:
            printf("si usted es profesor\n");
            cout<<"ingrese la clave de acceso: ";
            cin>>claveacceso;
            if(claveacceso!=clavetrue);
        }
    }
            while(claveacceso!=clavetrue);
            cout<<"\n\n acesso concedido.\n";
            getch();

        printf("esta es una evaluación cuenta con 10 preguntas de selección multiple \n");
        printf("pregunta 1 \n");
        printf("En que mes nos encontramos \n");
        printf("Indica tu respuesta \n");
        scanf("%i",&p1);
        if(p1==2){
        n1=1;
        }
        else{
            n1=0;
        }
        printf("pregunta 2 \n");
        printf("En que año estamos\n");
        printf("Indica tu respuesta \n");
        scanf("%i",&p2);
        if(p2==4){
        n2=1;
        }
        else{
            n2= 0;
        }
        printf("pregunta 3 \n");
        printf("Que lenguaje estoy usando en esta evaluación \n");
        printf("Indica tu respuesta \n");
        scanf("%i",&p3);
        if(p3==2){
        n3=1;
        }
        else{
            n3= 0;
        }
        printf("pregunta 4 \n");
        printf("A que nota corresponde esta evaluación \n");
        printf("Indica tu respuesta \n");
        scanf("%i",&p4);
        if(p4==2){
        n4=1;
        }
        else{
            n4= 0;
        }
        printf("pregunta 5 \n");
        printf("Cuanto dura la clase de Algoritmo y programación \n");
        printf("Indica tu respuesta \n");
        scanf("%i",&p5);
        if(p5==3){
        n5=1;
        }
        else{
            n5= 0;
        }
        printf("pregunta 6 \n");
        printf("Mejor seccion en el pinpon \n");
        printf("Indica tu respuesta \n");
        scanf("%i",&p6);
        if(p6==2){
        n6=1;
        }
        else{
            n6= 0;
        }
        printf("pregunta 7 \n");
        printf("De que asignatura es esta evaluación \n");
        printf("Indica tu respuesta \n");
        scanf("%i",&p7);
        if(p7==4){
        n7=1;
        }
        else{
            n7= 0;
        }
        printf("pregunta 8 \n");
        printf("La mejor sección es: \n");
        printf("Indica tu respuesta \n");
        scanf("%i",&p8);
        if(p8==2){
        n8=1;
        }
        else{
            n8= 0;
        }
        printf("pregunta 9 \n");
        printf("Jorge tobar es: \n");
        printf("Indica tu respuesta \n");
        scanf("%i",&p9);
        if(p9==4){
        n9=1;
        }
        else{
            n9= 0;
        }
        printf("pregunta 10 \n");
        printf("Alexis sanchez es: \n");
        printf("Indica tu respuesta \n");
        scanf("%i",&p10);
        if(p10==1){
        n10=1;
        }
        else{
            n10= 0;
        }
        resultado=n1+n2+n3+n4+n5+n6+n7+n8+n9+n10;
        printf("has respondido %i correctas",resultado);

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Al usar **scanf** el primer parametro es el formato con el que quieres que se guarde lo que va escribir en la consola, en tu código estableces que el nombre es ***%d***, osease decimal, lo que tienes que hacer es que cuando escribas una cadena de caracteres pongas el formato como string, osease ***%s***:

```
char nombre[260];

printf("\nIntroduzca su nombre: ");
scanf("%s",&nombre);
```

OJO que estas guardando nombre en una variable int, que solo permite numeros, no caractere, en el ejemplo que te puse es una manera correcta de hacerlo.

Suerte (y)